# Problem connecting android studio to Azure sql using java

Tags: java, android, sql, azure, connection

I'm trying to connect with android studio to my Azure sql cloud database.
Running the code I encounter ***this error:*** ***"Login failed due to client TLS version being less than minimal TLS version allowed by the server."***
i have already tried to set azure's lts to version 1.0.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static final String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://***.database.windows.net:1433;DatabaseName=***;user=***;password=***;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
public static final String name = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";

public static Connection conn = null;
public static PreparedStatement pst = null;
public static Statement stmt = null;
public static ResultSet rs = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String SQL = "select * from dbo.Person";
                Class.forName(name);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("FirstName"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to a mismatch in the TLS version settings in the firewall for the database on Azure End and the connection as shown:

**The following screenshot is an example of an incorrect configuration:**

Azure was asked to use TLS version **greater than TLS 1.2**, however, the connection used **TLS1.2 exactly**.

This would cause a mismatch.

a) **Firewall** (selected version **greater than TLS 1.2**):

[image: AzureSQL_Firewall_TLS.png]

b) **Connection** (At the connection level **selected as TLS1.2** exactly which does not match the above setting):

[image: Connection Properties in IICS]

**Therefore if you are selecting TLS1.2 at the connection level, the setting on Azure should be selected as greater than TLS 1.1 (i.e >TLS 1.1).**

To resolve this issue, ensure to choose compatible TLS Versions to ensure that the Secure Agent can connect successfully to the database .

Additionally, make sure that the Encryption Method Chosen for the connection is SSL or any other SSL-based option for this scenario.

This is because the TLS Settings will not be applied for the task at runtime if the Encryption Method is set to "None" causing task to fail at runtime with the same error message.